# Swing wait() and notify() on JDialog, the dialog does not show its components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, components, jdialog

I have a mouse listener that gets invoked when I move the mouse in the application window.
In the MouseEntered method, I invoke a ThreadB as such:

```
@Override
   public synchronized void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

     ..

     ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
     b.start();
     System.out.println("Before Sync!!!!!!!");
     synchronized(b) {
         try{
         System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
         b.wait();
     }catch(InterruptedException ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }       
    }
    System.out.println("After Sync!!!!!!!");
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
        
        @Override
        public void run(){
            synchronized(this){

                int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Loading process is in progress. Do you want to stop the process?", "Loading Accounts", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                
              
            if (dialogResult == 0) {
                System.out.println("Yes is chosen!!!!");
            }else {
                System.out.println("No is chosen!!!!");
            }

                System.out.println("before NOTIFY!!!!!!!");
            
                notify();
         }
      }
   }
```

The loading process is stopped as expected, but the dialog does not gets painted meaning it does not show its components.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can't do GUI things anywhere in your code, except if that code runs in the Event Dispatch Thread (the EDT). You're running it on a thread of your own creation; not allowed. Use e.g. `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, or the SwingWorker system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. When I use invokeLater, the process does not stop but the dialog shows fine. I need to capture the user's input first then parse that and then continue the process according to the user's input.